# python - in a list of strings, find all patterns with a minimum of n consecutive tokens that occurs in at least y entries

Tags: python, recursion

The task I am trying to accomplish is to write a function that would identify all patterns of at least n tokens that occur in at least y entries when searching within a list of strings.

For example:

```
list = ["Hello my name is foobar","Hello my favorite food is pizza","Hello my favorite food will never be broccoli","No my name is not barfoo", "Yes my name is foobar"]
```

Then

```
function(list, n=3, y=3)
["my name is"]

function(list, n=3, y=2)
["my name is", "my favorite food"]
```

I would like to use this function with extremely large lists. I was planning to do this the brute force way with multiple nested loops, but this would be extremely slow. I am wondering if there are more efficient ways to do this type of a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick function to do this.  In this function each sentence is broken in `n_tokens`-grams.  Wrapping `set()` around the `ngrams` will ensure that only distinct `ngrams` are included and if an `ngram` occurs multiple times in a sentence it won't be double-counted later.  Using `itertools` the `word_grams` from the sentences are combined and `Counter` will count the number of occurrence for each `ngram`.  Finally, the counts of the `gram_occur` are evaluated to see what grams occur most frequently.  The result is converted into a list of strings that meet your criteria.

```
from nltk import ngrams
import itertools
from collections import Counter


def count_ngrams(l, n_tokens, min_occur):
    word_grams = [set(ngrams(s.split(), n_tokens)) for s in l]

    gram_occur = Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(word_grams))

    return [" ".join([*words]) for (words, n) in gram_occur.items() if n >= min_occur]
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for. I am going to now try to use this function to find a good threshold for min_occur across all n_token sizes. Very helpful!